# Set spinnerMode programmatically

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

How can I change the **spinnerMode** when the button is pressed?
I mean mainly the method of implementing the change to the spinner and the rest I hope that I can do it :)

Let's say I have a spinner like below

```
val spinner= findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.Spinner)
```

I know you can apply something like this, but how do you implement it in the spinner shown above?

```
val setSpinnerMode = Spinner(this, null, android.R.style.Widget_Spinner, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN)
```

Or maybe someone has a better idea than the one shown above :)

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin you can try this

```
    val spinner = findViewById<View>(R.id.spinner) as Spinner
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this@MainActivity, 
                   R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list)
        
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = adapter
        spinner.performClick()
```